# How to return future from a function

Tags: scala, future

I'm getting data from an API using scala's Dispatch library.

In main, I have a function getSensorList() which returns a list of sensors attached to an ID for a device.

Dispatch uses Futures to do a request [Dispatch library](http://lollyrock.com/articles/scala-http-requests/)

How do I return the future back to main?

I followed this post to implement what I have: [Accessing value returned by scala futures](http://lollyrock.com/articles/scala-http-requests/)

```
import dispatch._, Defaults._
import scala.util.{Success, Failure}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

def getSensorList(uuid:String) = Future[String] {

val svc = url("https://example_api.com/services/api/v1/sensors/" + uuid + "/")

val response : Future[String] = Http(svc OK as.String)

}

object DispatchTestFunction{

def main (args: Array[String]) {

val result = getSensorList("example_device_ID)

result onComplete {
  case Success(content) => {
    println("Successful response" + content)
  }
  case Failure(t) => {
    println("An error has occurred: " + t.getMessage)
  }
}
}
}
```

---

Thanks for your help.

The API returns JSON type data therefore should `result` be of type JSON?

The error that I have with my code is `Type mismatch, expected string: actual is unit`

I have the return type of the future defined as a string but the complier looks at the last line of the function and thinks it should be of type unit - i.e. that it returns notting?

Thanks

```
import dispatch._, Defaults._
import scala.util.{Success, Failure}


def getSensorList(uuid:String) = Future[String] {

val svc = url("https://example_api.com/services/api/v1/sensors/" + uuid + "/")

val response : Future[String] = Http(svc OK as.String)

}

object DispatchTestFunction{

def main (args: Array[String]) {

val result = getSensorList("example_device_ID")

  result onComplete {
  case Success(content) => {
    println("Successful response" + content)
  }
  case Failure(t) => {
    println("An error has occurred: " + t.getMessage)
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: (In case you post code to check in a language where there is type inference, please add the inferred types at least to the parts of the question, in this case `result`.) How do you want to get the `Future` in the `main`? For me it seems you already have it. Not sure what you want to achieve. Do you want to `Await` the result? Or `map`?

Comment: Thank you for your help Gabor. The API returns JSON data therefore should `result` be of type JSON? Does that exist in Scala.

Comment: It depends on the lib dispatcher uses. I guess the result type is something like `val result: Future[/*List[*/JValue/*]*/] = ...`. An IDE or REPL can tell. For an akka/Scala `Future` you can get the result by `Await` to it (http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#blocking), in case you prefer to keep it in a `Future`, just `map` the `result` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I misunderstood your problem. Now it seems you had problem with the `getSensorList`, not how to handle the result.

Here is my take:

```
def getSensorList(uuid:String): Future[String] = {
    val svc = url("https://example_api.com/services/api/v1/sensors/" + uuid + "/")
    val response : Future[String] = Http(svc OK as.String)
    response
}
```

I have kept the `response` variable just in case you want to debug or further process before you return. The problem was that you just declared the result you want to return, but not returned. (`=` returns `Unit`, in Scala the assignment do not return the right hand side expression.) You are right that the `Unit` is kind of nothing (but not `Nothing`!), if you are familiar with Java/C/C++/C#, the equivalent is `void` (in Python it is I think `None`).